# Vector storing objects

Tags: c++, class, vector

I have created 3 classes.

- All class - storing all Groups
- Group class - Storing objects of students into vector.
- Studen class - storing information about a student.

I have a problem with All class - method printAllofThem it should iterate through Group objets and call method in printAll which should iterate though all Student objects and call printAtributes, but the output looks like this :

```
all . printAllofThem ( );
```

Output:

```
-------------------
-------------------

-------------------
```

Expected output:

```
-------------------
name: Mark | age: 20 | A1

name: Alan | age: 20 | A1

name: Eric | age: 19 | A1

-------------------
name: John | age: 19 | B1
```

It gives me the right output only when i call it like this in main function:

```
A1 . printAll  ( );
B1 . printAll  ( );
```

Code :

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Student
{
  public:
    Student ( string name, int age, string cllass );
    void printAtributes ( void ) const;

  protected:
    string                    nameOfStudent;
    string                    whichClass;
    int                       ageOfStudent;
};
//========================================================================
class Group
{
  public:
    Group ( void );
    bool addStudent ( const Student & X );
    void printAll( void ) const;

  protected:
    vector<Student> vectorOfStudents;
};
//========================================================================
class All
{
  public:
    All ( void );
    bool addToAll ( const Group & T );
    void printAllofThem ( void ) const;

  protected:
    vector<Group> vectorOfAll;
};
//========================================================================
All::All ( void )
{
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool All::addToAll ( const Group & T )
{
  vectorOfAll . push_back ( T );
  return true;
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
void All::printAllofThem ( void ) const  // Function which iterate thought group objects
{
  cout << "-------------------" << endl;
  for ( const auto & allofthem : vectorOfAll )
  {
    allofthem . printAll  (  );
    cout << endl;
  }
}
//------------------------------------------------------------------------
Student::Student ( string name, int age, string cllass )
             :nameOfStudent( name ), ageOfStudent( age ), whichClass( cllass )
{
}
//--------------------------------------------------------------------
void Student::printAtributes ( void ) const
{
  cout << "name: " << nameOfStudent << " | " << "age: " << ageOfStudent << " | " << whichClass << endl;
}
//============================================================================
Group::Group ( void )
{
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
bool Group::addStudent ( const Student & X )
{
  vectorOfStudents . push_back ( X );
  return true;
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
void Group::printAll ( void ) const
{
  cout << "-------------------" << endl;
  for ( const auto & student : vectorOfStudents )
  {
    student . printAtributes (  );
    cout << endl;
  }
}
//----------------------------------------------------------------------------
int main()
{

  All           all; // Representing all classes
  Group         A1;
  Group         B1;

  all . addToAll ( A1 );
  all . addToAll ( B1 );

  A1 . addStudent ( Student ( "Mark", 20, "A1" ) );
  A1 . addStudent ( Student ( "Alan", 20, "A1") );
  A1 . addStudent ( Student ( "Eric", 19, "A1" ) );

  B1 . addStudent ( Student ( "John", 19, "B1" ) );

  A1 . printAll  ( );
  B1 . printAll  ( );

  all . printAllofThem ( );

  return 0;    

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming.  Further reading: **[How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)**

Comment: You are calling, e.g. `all.addToAll(A1)` *before* modifying it with  `A1.addStudent(...)`. These change will not automatically propagate to the copy of `A1` that was previously added to your `all` object.

Comment: `addToAll` does `vector.push_back` which in turn makes a copy of what you are pushing. Since you call `addToAll` with empty groups, the `All` object is empty. Try doing `addToAll` after `addStudent`s

Comment: spaces around `.` is not a common style and may look very odd to many C++ programmers (styles for spacing around `(` and `)` is more varied, but you've gone to the extreme here too).

Answer (score 1):

When you added `A1` and `B1` to `all`, both of those groups were still empty - and you took copies of them. When you subsequently added students to `A1` and `B1`, those groups got new students, but the groups in `all` are entirely different groups - they remain unmodified.

Either

- Add the students to the groups *first*, *then* add the groups to `all`.
- Have the groups be `shared_ptr<Group>` instead, with `All` having a `vector<shared_ptr<Group>>`. This way, the ordering doesn't matter since there will only be two group objects that everybody is simply sharing ownership of.

---

Side-note. This is a truly excessive amount of spaces:

```
B1 . printAll  ( );
```

You don't need... any of them:

```
B1.printAll();
```

Comment: About those spaces it looks more tabular to me coud it cause any problems?

Comment: @kvway Looking tabular is a weird goal for code. But no, whitespace doesn't matter in C++.